# qsub job array, where each job uses a single process?

Tags: pbs, qsub, torque

I have a job script with the following PBS specifications at the beginning:

```
#PBS -t 0-99
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
```

The first line says that this is a job array, with jobs indexed from 0 to 99. 
I want each individual indexed job to use only a single node and a single core per node, hence my second PBS line. But I am worried that TORQUE `qsub` will interpret the second line as saying that the whole job array should run sequentially on a single core.

How does TORQUE `qsub` interpret the PBS second line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It interprets it as 100 jobs that should each use 1 execution slot on one node. For more information, please look at the [qsub documentation](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/suite/8-0/basic/help.htm#topics/torque/commands/qsub.htm) and look for the details on the -t switch.

Comment: i'm wondering if you can comment on the use of job array vs something called bundling described here: http://www.sdsc.edu/support/user_guides/tscc.html#bundling-serial, which one is more efficient to use?